# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '&' &#x27;

Tags: javascript, django, graph, django-views, plotly

I have a django website where i want to include a js graph that plots prices against dates. I use (Plotly) https://plotly.com/javascript/

My problem is when i pass an array of dates (formatted 'yyyy/mm/dd')
from my view in views.py into my html file which includes the code for my graph the dates have '&#x27 ;' either side of each date.

*views.py*

```
context = {
    "dates":['2022/12/03', '2022/12/04', '2022/12/05'],
}

return render(request, "App/minifig_page.html", context=context)
```

*inside html*

```
<script>
...
var xArray = {{dates}};
...
</script>
```

`xArray in browser view sources` [&#x27 ;2022/12/03', &#x27 ;2022/12/04&#x27 ;, &#x27 ;2022/12/05&#x27 ;]

This causes the dates to be improperly formatted and therefore the graph does not display.

Comment: The list of dates should be JSON-encoded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is *not* how you render a JSON blob. You can use the [**`|json_script`** template filter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script):

```
{{ dates|json_script:xArray }}
<script>
…
const value = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('xArray').textContent);
…
</script>
```

This will then JSON encode the data, and let it load with `JSON.parse`. It is also better that the "outer" data structure is a dictionary, not an array due to a [*subtle JSON vulnerability* <sup>[haacked.com]</sup>](https://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx/).